# In App Purchase in Android through webview

Tags: android, paypal, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to have a browser view with the paypal option for in app purchase with the android application. The transaction can taken by the browser itself not from the application.

If i am publish the application in google play store whether it vialote the google terms and conditions?

Comment: Yes, it will violate Google's T&C. Why don't you use Google's IAP service?

Comment: i'm not going to use paypal sdk or some other sdk for purchase transaction. Its like the purchase taken from website. Its similar to purchase happening in web browser not from the application. Even now the application violating the google's T&C?

Comment: Yes. All in app purchases in Android apps HAVE to use Google Checkout, except in two cases - 1. The purchases are for actual, physical goods and 2. Whatever you are purchasing can be consumed elsewhere like digital videos, music, and books

Comment: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

Read the section about Paid and free applications

Comment: Looks like the link moved here: https://play.google.com/about/monetization.html#payments